# How to Pass Manual Parameter Order in Javascript like C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

Generally speaking, in C# i have a method like this;

```
public virtual IPagedList<Manufacturer> GetAllManufacturers(string manufacturerName = "",
            int pageIndex = 0,
            int pageSize = int.MaxValue, 
            bool showHidden = false)
{
     //rest of the code
}
```

and when i need to specify the parameter order /override/call manually, i do this;

```
//manually saying, pageIndex should be as parameter 1 and showHidden should be true and order no 2
GetAllManufacturers(pageIndex:10, showHidden:true);
```

Similarly in JavaScript, i have the following function;

```
var CommonManager = function () {
    var
        displayWizard = function (wizardName, formName, leaveStepCallBack) {
            leaveAStepCallback('test');

            function leaveAStepCallback(obj) {
                if (typeof (leaveStepCallBack) == "function") {
                    //yaheeeeeee callback is there
                    return leaveStepCallBack();
                }
                //oh no callback, handle the defaults
                return validateSteps(); // return false to stay on step and true to continue navigation
            }
        };
    return {
        displayWizard: displayWizard
    };
}();
```

and if i want to handle the callback i do call it like this;

```
CommonManager.displayWizard($('#wizard'), $('#attributeForm'), function() {
    //i handled it, don't need to call default function
});
```

if i don't want to handle the callback, i do like this;

```
CommonManager.displayWizard($('#wizard'), $('#attributeForm'), undefined);
```

Note that, i have several optional parameters but i skipped it here. In my orginal case, i am passing `undefined`, `undefined`, `undefined` 
So my questions are; 
**1) - How do i make it adjusted** to i can call it like this;

```
//Notice the order of the parameter
CommonManager.displayWizard(attributeForm : $('#attributeForm'), wizard: $('#wizard'));
```

**2) - if 1 isn't possible then How do i skipped passing** this `undefined` as calling the Orignal Callback and call it like this

```
CommonManager.displayWizard($('#wizard'), $('#attributeForm'));
```

i could use the above code directly but i have the last parameter which need to be passed as well like this;

```
   CommonManager.displayWizard(wizard, attributeForm, undefined,undefined, true);
```

**3) - Lastly i wanna know, if i am following the right way of doing or handling this optional parameters** 
 
Please, let me know if the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i make it adjusted

You can make your function take a parameter object, like this:

```
CommonManager.displayWizard({ attributeForm : $('#attributeForm'), wizard: $('#wizard') });
```

You could combine both approaches. For instance, in jQuery these lines are equivalent:

```
$(this).css("color", "red");
$(this).css({ color: "red" });
```

This is because the `css` function checks if its first parameter is an object and acts accordingly.

> if 1 isn't possible then How do i skipped passing

You already can use the following:

```
CommonManager.displayWizard($('#wizard'), $('#attributeForm') /* no undefined here */);
```

If you skip a parameter **at the end of the argument list**, the default value passed to the function will be `undefined`.

> Lastly i wanna know, if i am following the right way of doing or handling this optional parameters

If I know I may want to expand on a function's parameters in the future and some of them are/will be optional, I often create the function so that it accepts a single parameter: an object containing all the values I need to pass to the function.

This way, I can add *parameters* with default values, and still have calls that skip some values without breaking anything.

Comment: i can't skipp passing `undefined` becuase at last parameter, i m passing value like this `         CommonManager.displayWizard(wizard, attributeForm, undefined,undefined, true);`

Comment: @DotNetDreamer Ah yes, in that case you still have to pass `undefined`. I guess your best bet would be the single parameter approach.

Comment: yes, i updated the question (my no2 point). One idea that comes in my mind, is also to move optional parameters to last then i can follow directly wihtout passing `undefined`

Comment: Yes, optional parameters should always be last anyway, but it won't solve the problem by itself because you still could have multiple optional parameters and in that case you'd still have to pass `undefined` in some cases.